# How to properly create a root view controller?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, root

After upgrading to xCode 4.2 I am getting the following warning...

> Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

After reading as much as I could find on line about the RootViewController I am not sure whether I have created my root view controller properly. I created it a long time ago when I was first learning to program in xCode.

One question I have is it ok to name the root view controller something other than RootViewController. Every example I see now has it named RootViewController. I also see it synthesized in the app delegate like this...

```
@synthesize rootViewController = _rootViewController;
```

I do not understand what this is doing. Why not just...

```
@synthesize rootViewController;
```

In any event I changed the name of my root view controller to RootViewController and followed the example I found at [cupsofcocoa.com](http://cupsofcocoa.com/tag/tutorial/). But even after the changes I am still getting the "...expected to have a root controller..." warning.

If someone has the time to take a look and let me know what I am missing, I have listed the the significant portions of my initialization code below.

Thanks,

John

```
  //RootViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController  {   

}
@end
```

.

```
  //RootViewController.m
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "JetLoggerAppDelegate.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@end
```

.

```
  //JetLoggerAppDelegate.h   my app delegate 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class RootViewController;

@interface JetLoggerAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    RootViewController *rootViewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RootViewController *rootViewController;
@end
```

.

```
  //.m app delegate
#import "JetLoggerAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"   //I don't think I need this here

@implementation JetLoggerAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize rootViewController = _rootViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([launchOptions count] == 0) {
        _rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];        
        return YES;

    }else{
        [JLHelper showAlertWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"launchOptions: %@", launchOptions]];

    }

    return NO;

}
```

.

```
  //main.m
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"JetLoggerAppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([launchOptions count] == 0) {
        _rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
        **[window addSubview:_rootViewController.view];**
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;

    }else{
        [JLHelper showAlertWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"launchOptions: %@", launchOptions]];
 return NO;
    }
return nil;
}
```

Put return NO inside else statement and on the end put return nil; Hope this help.

Comment: if you want to support devices with ios < 4.0 you have to check for the version before setting the rootViewController property of the window

Comment: Actually I did have the line to addSubview. I tried returning nil but it throws a warning "incompatible pointer to integer conversion....". In any event I am still getting the "Application are expected to have a Root View controller..." warning at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Applications are expected to have a root view controller

Replace in AppDelegate

```
 [window addSubview:[someController view]];
```

to

```
 [self.window setRootViewController:someController];
```