# How to set iOS device orientation only landscape?

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm writing a simple app under `MacOS` using `Xcode`. I want my app to be in landscape mode always. So I set landscape orientation in project properties. But when I add a button to my `window.subview`, this button doesn't appear in landscape position.

I have only AppDelegate class. I've changed function:
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

I've added:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2 - 50, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2,
                            100, 100)];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.window addSubview:button];
```

[image]

Update: I added 
    [self.window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2)];

and got:
[image]

Comment: please post your code too

Comment: check orientation of interface in interface builder

Comment: how did you define the `–shouldAutorotate` method for `iOS6+`, and how did you define the `–shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` for `<iOS6` in your view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it like this:

1. create my own RootViewController (like in [How to create root view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782796/how-to-properly-create-a-root-view-controller))
2. then:

   ```
   self.rootController = [[AppRootViewController alloc] init];

   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController;
   [self.window addSubview:self.rootController.view];

   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   ....

   [[[self.window rootViewController] view] addSubview:button];
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Select your target project and make sure you have choose following landscape mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two mechanisms that control this.

You already know about the target properties.  If this is all you change, this should take care of it.

There is also a lower level control, which you might have picked up from old template code. For each view controller, if you implement the method

```
shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation:
```

That will override the setting for the target.  I suspect the superclasses implementation just refers to the target setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` property in YourProject-info.plist as follow, then it will only support landscape orientation.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
</array>
```

but do not know what's the meaning with your two pictures

Comment: I've already did that, but only adding my own root controller helped.